# Is the “of” in "A role you can be proud of" correct?

Tags: prepositions

This is for a headline on a website:

"A role you can be proud of"

One member of our team seems to disagree with the word "of"

Comment: Did your team member explain why they felt it wasn't correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is a perfectly good sentence.

Some people will maintain that 'sentences should not end in prepositions'. They would suggest that you should say:

> A role of which you can be proud.

However, this is not a rule modern grammar experts believe in. In normal standard English, speakers and writers end sentences with prepositions all the time. Furthermore, 'to be proud of' is a phrasal verb, and it is more natural to use the words in their customary order than force a more elaborate structure on the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If this is correct:

*I threw a lot of balls and walked a lot of batters. Not something I'm proud of, but something I learned from.*

Randy Johnson

> "A role you can be proud of"

will be correct too.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave off the "of" (if this is what your team member is suggesting) then the phrase makes no sense. "to be proud of" takes an object, but "to be proud" does not. The subject is "you" and the object is "a role". Look what happens when you reorder the words in the sentence - you could say

> You can be proud of a (this) role

But you could not say

> You can be proud a (this) role